# Loading swf file in iframe with LightGallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, lightgallery

I am using [lightGallery](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery) to load videos into an iframe that gets embeded in the lightgallery popup.

Problem is if I provide non-HTML5-videos for old browsers, using my own flash player, the iframe stays empty (black). If I open the video in a new tab, instead of lightgallery, it loads without any problem.

The web developer console is empty, which is my biggest problem, since I cannot track down the error. Note, everything is on the same domain.

Example code from within the iframe:

```
<object id="videoPlayerObject" name="videoPlayerObject" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="1021" height="770">
    <param name="movie" value="vid/video_player.swf">
    <param name="flashvars" value="flv=filename.flv&amp;width=1021&amp;height=770">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="salign" value="lt">
    <embed id="videoPlayerEmbed" name="videoPlayerEmbed" src="vid/video_player.swf" flashvars="flv=filename.flv&amp;width=1021&amp;height=770" allowFullScreen="true" width="1021" height="770" allowScriptAccess="always" salign="lt" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
```

I have also tried swfobject, but the same problem.

Can anybody help me? How can I find out more about the error? Unfortunately the developer is not answering on github.

PS: I tried the same iframe embed with fancybox, there it works. So it must be lightgallery that has some problems with flash files.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Add wmode opaque to the object:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Then it shows up!